# Cross-Section from ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I would like to ask if there is a solution to find the cross-section from ParametricPlot3D, for instance if I want the cross-section along the x-axis. Specifically, I would want to know the z-value but have no idea how I should retrieve it since I already have the x and y value.

[image]

```
Clear[u, a, b, c, d, f, t, a1, b1, c1, d1, f1]
u1 = {0, 0.1};
u2 = {1, 0};
u3 = {1.7, 1};
u4 = {2, 2};
u5 = {1.8, 2.8};

u5 = {1.8, 2.8};
u6 = {1, 3.5};

u7 = {1.5, 4.2};

u8 = {1.5, 4.5};

basis1 = ((4 - t)^3)/6;
basis2 = (((3*((t - 1)^3)) - (24*((t - 1)^2)) + (60*(t - 1)) - 44)/ 6);
basis3 = (((-3.*((t - 2)^3)) + (12.*((t - 2)^2)) - (12.*(t - 2)) + 4)/ 6);
basis4 = ((t - 3)^3)/6;

curve1 = (u1*basis1) + (u1*basis2) + (u1*basis3) + (u2*basis4);
curve2 = (u1*basis1) + (u1*basis2) + (u2*basis3) + (u3*basis4);
curve3 = (u1*basis1) + (u2*basis2) + (u3*basis3) + (u4*basis4);
curve4 = (u2*basis1) + (u3*basis2) + (u4*basis3) + (u5*basis4);
curve5 = (u3*basis1) + (u4*basis2) + (u5*basis3) + (u6*basis4);
curve6 = (u4*basis1) + (u5*basis2) + (u6*basis3) + (u7*basis4);
curve7 = (u5*basis1) + (u6*basis2) + (u7*basis3) + (u8*basis4);
curve8 = (u6*basis1) + (u7*basis2) + (u8*basis3) + (u8*basis4);
curve9 = (u7*basis1) + (u8*basis2) + (u8*basis3) + (u8*basis4);

A = ParametricPlot[{curve1, curve2, curve3, curve4, curve5, curve6, curve7, curve8, curve9}, {t, 3, 4}]

cp = ListPlot[{u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8}];

B = Show[A, cp]

a = {curve1[[1]], curve1[[2]], 0};
b = {curve2[[1]], curve2[[2]], 0};
c = {curve3[[1]], curve3[[2]], 0};
d = {curve4[[1]], curve4[[2]], 0};
f = {curve5[[1]], curve5[[2]], 0};
g = {curve6[[1]], curve6[[2]], 0};
h = {curve7[[1]], curve7[[2]], 0};
i = {curve8[[1]], curve8[[2]], 0};
j = {curve9[[1]], curve9[[2]], 0};


T = {{Cos[w], 0, Sin[w]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[w], 0, Cos[w]}};

a1 = a.T;
b1 = b.T;
c1 = c.T;
d1 = d.T;
f1 = f.T;
g1 = g.T;
h1 = h.T;
i1 = i.T;
j1 = j.T;

ParametricPlot3D[{a1, b1, c1, d1, f1, g1, h1, i1, j1}, {t, 3, 4}, {w, 
  0, Pi}, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotStyle -> {Red, LightPink}, 
 Mesh -> None]

ParametricPlot3D[{a1, b1, c1, d1, f1, g1, h1, i1, j1}, {t, 3, 4}, {w, 0, Pi},
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, LightPink}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set the option `MeshFunctions`. The following plot the surface intersected with the surface given by `F[x,y,z] == 0`:

```
F = {x, y, z} \[Function] x;
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{a1, b1, c1, d1, f1, g1, h1, i1, j1}, {t, 3, 4}, {w, 0,Pi},
    PlotStyle -> None,
    MeshFunctions -> {F},
    Mesh -> {{1}},
    MeshStyle -> {Thick}
    ];
```

You can turn the resulting polygonal line into a `MeshRegion` with

```
curve = DiscretizeGraphics@plot
```

and extract the coordinates with

```
MeshCoordinates[curve]
```